# Fluid transitions with fading in and out when changing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think might be better doing this in CSS but not 100% sure so if someone knows and can provide solution would be great but in regards to the jQuery method i am using. It fades the image out but when it loads the new one in does not seem to fade.

Anyone have any ideas?

```js
$("#product_color_select li").on("click", function() {
  var select_product_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
  sd_refresh_product_form_update(select_product_id);
});

var product_color_select_first = $("#product_color_select li:first-child").attr('data-larger');
$("#larger-colour").fadeIn("slow", function() {
  $('#larger-colour').addClass(product_color_select_first);
});

$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseover", function() {
  var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
  $("#larger-colour").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('#larger-colour').removeClass();
  });
  $("#larger-colour").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(select_product_swatch);
  });
});
```

```css
#product_color_select {
  width: 76%;
  float: left;
}
#product_color_select li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  text-indent: -999999em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 2px 5px 0;
}
#larger-colour {
  float: right;
  max-width: 86px;
  width: 86px;
  height: 62px;
}
/* interior colours */

#product_color_select li.eco-weave,
#larger-colour.eco-weave {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/eco-weave.png');
}
#product_color_select li.aubergine-dream,
#larger-colour.aubergine-dream {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/aubergine-dream.png');
}
#product_color_select li.lime-citrus,
#larger-colour.lime-citrus {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/lime-citrus.png');
}
#product_color_select li.blue-jazz,
#larger-colour.blue-jazz {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/blue-jazz.png');
}
#product_color_select li.sakura-pink,
#larger-colour.sakura-pink {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/sakura-pink.png');
}
#product_color_select li.hot-chocolate,
#larger-colour.hot-chocolate {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/hot-chocolate.png');
}
#product_color_select li.tundra-spring,
#larger-colour.tundra-spring {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/tundra-spring.png');
}
#product_color_select li.black-sapphire,
#larger-colour.black-sapphire {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/black-sapphire.png');
}
#product_color_select li.luscious-grey,
#larger-colour.luscious-grey {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/luscious-grey.png');
}
#product_color_select li.wildberry-deluxe,
#larger-colour.wildberry-deluxe {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/wildberry-deluxe.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="fabric-select" id="product_color_select">
  <li class=" aubergine-dream" data-value="745" data-larger="aubergine-dream" title="Aubergine Dream">Aubergine Dream</li>
  <li class=" black-sapphire" data-value="746" data-larger="black-sapphire" title="Black Sapphire">Black Sapphire</li>
  <li class=" wildberry-deluxe" data-value="727" data-larger="wildberry-deluxe" title="Wildberry Deluxe">Wildberry Deluxe</li>
  <li class=" tundra-spring" data-value="747" data-larger="tundra-spring" title="Tundra Spring">Tundra Spring</li>
  <li class="selected luscious-grey" data-value="744" data-larger="luscious-grey" title="Luscious Grey">Luscious Grey</li>
  <li class=" sakura-pink" data-value="743" data-larger="sakura-pink" title="Sakura Pink">Sakura Pink</li>
  <li class=" lime-citrus" data-value="748" data-larger="lime-citrus" title="Lime Citrus">Lime Citrus</li>
  <li class=" eco-weave" data-value="742" data-larger="eco-weave" title="Eco Weave">Eco Weave</li>
  <li class=" blue-jazz" data-value="749" data-larger="blue-jazz" title="Blue Jazz">Blue Jazz</li>
  <li class=" hot-chocolate" data-value="741" data-larger="hot-chocolate" title="Hot Chocolate">Hot Chocolate</li>
</ul>

<div id="larger-colour" class="aubergine-dream" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it, it's adding the background picture after the fadeIn animation finished. That's why it suddenly appears. You want to set the background before fading it in.

```js
$("#product_color_select li").on("click", function() {
  var select_product_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
  sd_refresh_product_form_update(select_product_id);
});

var product_color_select_first = $("#product_color_select li:first-child").attr('data-larger');
$("#larger-colour").fadeIn("slow", function() {
  $('#larger-colour').addClass(product_color_select_first);
});

$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseover", function() {
  var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
  var thumbnail = $('#larger-colour');
  thumbnail.stop();
  thumbnail.fadeOut("fast", function() {
    thumbnail.removeClass();
    thumbnail.addClass(select_product_swatch);
    thumbnail.fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#product_color_select {
  width: 76%;
  float: left;
}
#product_color_select li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  text-indent: -999999em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 2px 5px 0;
}
#larger-colour {
  float: right;
  max-width: 86px;
  width: 86px;
  height: 62px;
}
/* interior colours */

#product_color_select li.eco-weave,
#larger-colour.eco-weave {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/eco-weave.png');
}
#product_color_select li.aubergine-dream,
#larger-colour.aubergine-dream {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/aubergine-dream.png');
}
#product_color_select li.lime-citrus,
#larger-colour.lime-citrus {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/lime-citrus.png');
}
#product_color_select li.blue-jazz,
#larger-colour.blue-jazz {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/blue-jazz.png');
}
#product_color_select li.sakura-pink,
#larger-colour.sakura-pink {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/sakura-pink.png');
}
#product_color_select li.hot-chocolate,
#larger-colour.hot-chocolate {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/hot-chocolate.png');
}
#product_color_select li.tundra-spring,
#larger-colour.tundra-spring {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/tundra-spring.png');
}
#product_color_select li.black-sapphire,
#larger-colour.black-sapphire {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/black-sapphire.png');
}
#product_color_select li.luscious-grey,
#larger-colour.luscious-grey {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/luscious-grey.png');
}
#product_color_select li.wildberry-deluxe,
#larger-colour.wildberry-deluxe {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/wildberry-deluxe.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="fabric-select" id="product_color_select">
  <li class=" aubergine-dream" data-value="745" data-larger="aubergine-dream" title="Aubergine Dream">Aubergine Dream</li>
  <li class=" black-sapphire" data-value="746" data-larger="black-sapphire" title="Black Sapphire">Black Sapphire</li>
  <li class=" wildberry-deluxe" data-value="727" data-larger="wildberry-deluxe" title="Wildberry Deluxe">Wildberry Deluxe</li>
  <li class=" tundra-spring" data-value="747" data-larger="tundra-spring" title="Tundra Spring">Tundra Spring</li>
  <li class="selected luscious-grey" data-value="744" data-larger="luscious-grey" title="Luscious Grey">Luscious Grey</li>
  <li class=" sakura-pink" data-value="743" data-larger="sakura-pink" title="Sakura Pink">Sakura Pink</li>
  <li class=" lime-citrus" data-value="748" data-larger="lime-citrus" title="Lime Citrus">Lime Citrus</li>
  <li class=" eco-weave" data-value="742" data-larger="eco-weave" title="Eco Weave">Eco Weave</li>
  <li class=" blue-jazz" data-value="749" data-larger="blue-jazz" title="Blue Jazz">Blue Jazz</li>
  <li class=" hot-chocolate" data-value="741" data-larger="hot-chocolate" title="Hot Chocolate">Hot Chocolate</li>
</ul>

<div id="larger-colour" class="aubergine-dream" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: I have been playing aorund with this and nothing someone, if you hover multiple items it takes time to catch up. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You only need to `stop()` the current animation, instead of waiting for it to finish. I've edited the post, so it works this way now.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to optimize your code and solve it my way so...

Just replace this:

```
$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseover", function() {
  var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
  $("#larger-colour").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('#larger-colour').removeClass();
  });
  $("#larger-colour").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(select_product_swatch);
  });
});
```

by this:

```
$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseenter", function () {
    var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
    $('#larger-colour').stop().fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(select_product_swatch).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqjc9vz3/) :)

Comment: @James The code animation doesn't 'lags' in this one :) Any other requirements?